# Why does "if not a := say_empty()" raise a SyntaxError?

Tags: python, python-3.x, walrus-operator

[PEP 572](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) introduces the assignement operator ("walrus operator").

The following code works, and outputs `empty`

```
def say_empty():
    return ''

if a := say_empty():
    print("not empty")
else:
    print("empty")
```

I tried to negate the condition:

```
def say_empty():
    return ''

if not a := say_empty():
    print("empty")
else:
    print("not empty")
```

This raises a `SyntaxError`

```
    if not a := say_empty():
       ^
SyntaxError: cannot use assignment expressions with operator
```

The given error is clear, I am however wondering why this limitation was put in place.

PEP 572 explains why using the assignment in iterations is problematic (and raises `SyntaxError`), but I did not find anything about boolean ones.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[Operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) indicates that `:=` has a lower precedence than `not`. So `not a :=` is read as trying to assign to `not a`, hence the syntax error.

You can use parentheses to clarify the meaning:

```
if not (a := say_empty()):
    ...
```